# Error 500 - Ajax Response (No details on client but works on localhost)

Tags: c#, ajax, response, internal-server-error

I'm currently working on a change of password exception handling on server side. So, if the change of password throws an exception on server side (i.e. new password does not fulfill the security requirements) there is an error handled like this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            context.Response.End();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

Then, the failure is read in AJAX handler, in javascript:

```
failure: function(response, options) {
    loadMask.hide();
    if (response.status != -1) {
        if (response.responseText.indexOf("title") == -1) {
           Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', response.responseText);
        }
        else {
           var idx1 = response.responseText.indexOf("title") + 6;
           var idx2 = response.responseText.indexOf("/title") - 1; 
           if (idx1 > 0) {
               Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', response.responseText.substring(idx1, idx2));
           }
           else {
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', 'No change of password');
           }
         }
     }
```

And the problem is:

- Everything works fine locally, the detailed exception is written correctly and saved in the response (thus, the responseText displays proper ex.Message).
- However, when the application is imported on client computer, there is always '500 - Internal server error.'

I'm almost 99% sure that the Web.config files are identical on both workstations.

Can the problem be within the IIS settings?

Best regards,
loopdster

Comment: Can you inspect the client requests and see what's passed to IIS. 

And also many turn on request tracing and see what happens on the server.

Comment: When working locally, are you using the visual studio webserver (Cassini) or local IIS/IISExpress?

Comment: Ok, finally I was able to solve the problem.

The application consists of three different machines, connected, whereas each of those is responsible for different tasks - to summarize, I had to setup proper error displaying (to: detailed) on all of three machines to make it work.